# load a menu partial view on my layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, razor, menu, partial-views

i need/want to load a partial view that contains my menu, the menu is generated according to the user Roles in menuController, the result is a string that contains a `<ul> <li>` menu type.

i know that using `html.raw()` and pass the string using the viewbag it works. but how can i insert the menu on the layout? should i use a partial view? and how?

i also know that i can use ajax but i will like a sync approach

im using mvc4 and razor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

murphy's law at his finest, search for 1 hour, ask on stackoverflow, next link = answer lol
i use @html.action